# JQuery Passing a parameter and a callback in a ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have made a php file that takes ajax calls so I can return things from a database. But I have some issues getting the JQuery side to work.

```
function phpFunction(funktion, callback){
    $.ajax()({
        global: false,
        url: "./system/functions.php?ajax="+funktion,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

and I try to run it with this

```
phpFunction("getImageUrl()",function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

But nothing happens, I don't even get an empty alert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple syntax error. This...

```
$.ajax()({
```

should be this...

```
$.ajax({
```

I'd also use set a request method (POST / GET / etc) and use the `data` param...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'system/functions.php',
    type: 'GET',
    global: false,
    data: { ajax: funktion },
    success: callback
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, I didn't how to write the data param, I'm new to javascript, and jquery